# Executable taking advantage of multiple processors

Tags: .net, multiprocessing, cpu

I'm designing an application that will consist of one "manager" executable and 1 to n instances of a "daemon" executable that are started and managed by the former.  I would like to take full advantage of the number of CPU cores.

My question is: can (and should) I control this behavior using [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), even if each daemon executable doesn't itself use multiple threads?  Or is that something that MS Windows automatically controls for me, i.e. does Windows automatically load balance processes that start up between multiple cores?

Answer (score 0):

I'am sure Windows will take care of this. One process will be executed on one core. Which core the application use, will and should be decided by the os. If you start a new thread, the os will decide on which core the thread runs. You should just manage your processes and let Windows do his job.

That's way we pay a lot of money for licenses :)

Comment: I doubt the accuracy of your statement that "all started threads in the application will run on the same CPU core".  This would defeat the purpose of threading within a single process.

Comment: @MichaelPetito no, thats correct. bad choise of words. I mean, as long as one thread is running, it will not change the core. I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Windows will schedule your multiple daemon processes across the available CPU resources, including multiple cores.

Even though each process may be single threaded, you will still achieve parallel processing by running multiple processes on a multi-core machine.

Note that each daemon process may not be strictly scheduled to a separate core. It's entirely possible that all of your daemon processes will be scheduled at different times on the same core if they're not very busy. It's also possible that they will be moved from one core to another while "running" (although that incurs some expense). The purpose of the Windows Scheduler is to optimize the use of the available CPU resources.

For more information on how the Windows Scheduler operates, I'd suggest you check [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681917(v=vs.85).aspx).